# Properties of some operator on vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $\circ$ is an operation on $\Bbb R^2$ with the following properties:

1. For any $\vec p,\vec q \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $(t \vec p ) \circ \vec q = t(\vec p \circ \vec q)$ holds.
2. For any $\vec p, \vec q, \vec r \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\vec p \circ (\vec q + \vec r) = \vec p \circ \vec q + \vec p \circ \vec r$ holds.
3. For any $\vec p, \vec q \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\vec p \circ \vec q = -\vec q \circ \vec p$ holds.
4. For any $\vec p, \vec q, \vec r \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(\vec p \circ \vec q) \circ \vec r = (\vec p \cdot \vec r)\vec q - (\vec q \cdot \vec r)\vec p$ holds.

Why is it then true that $\vec p \circ \vec q = \vec 0$ all the time?

Comment: Does a dot denote the usual scalar product? If so, it is easy to find three vectors such that the RHS of 4) is not zero, while you claim that the LHS must always be zero.

Comment: Dot denote dot(scalar) product.

Comment: And $\circ$ is just an operator we are defining. ($\cdot$ is usually scalar product)

Comment: Ok, then I claim that the rules 1--4 are incompatible. I cannot fully answer since the question has been put on hold.

Comment: @AndreaMori I believe that is the intention, that the rules are "incompatible" and hence the only possibility is that $\vec{p} \cdot \vec {q} = 0$. (I'm assuming it's the scalar 0, and not the 0 vector ...) We can trivially verify that this definition satisfies the conditions, hence the rules are not incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the operation $\circ$ is *inner*, i.e.
$$
\circ:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2
$$
and satisfies rules 1.--4. as stated (else, 4. would make no sense).

By antisimmetricity (rule 3.) $\vec v\circ\vec v=0$ for all $\vec v\in\Bbb R^2$.

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{\vec e_1,\vec e_2\}$. By bilinearity and what we just observed, the operation $\circ$ is left completely determined by the value
$$
\vec w=\vec e_1\circ\vec e_2=a\vec e_1+b\vec e_2.
$$
Now, applying 4.
$$
0=\vec w\circ\vec w=(\vec e_1\circ\vec e_2)\circ\vec w=(\vec e_1\cdot\vec w)\vec e_2-(\vec e_2\cdot\vec w)\vec e_1=a\vec e_2-b\vec e_1.
$$
By linear independence of basis vectors, $a=b=0$, so that $\circ$ needs to be the constant zero function.

**BUT**: let now $\vec r=c\vec e_1+d\vec e_2\neq\vec0$, so that $(c,d)\neq(0,0)$. Rule 4. would yield
$$
\vec 0=(\vec e_1\circ\vec e_2)\circ\vec r=c\vec e_2-d\vec e_1\neq\vec 0
$$
(again by the linear independence of basis vectors) which is obviously impossible.

**THUS** no such a function exists, not even the constant zero function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Take a look at the outer product in $\mathbb R^3$ and restrict one component to be constant. What do you see?

Comment: This would only prove that _one model_ (rule) of the given vector product always yield $\vec 0$. The task of then deciding whether there are other models which yield other results is just as hard as the original question.

Comment: @Arthur that's true but it should help visualising the problem.